# Getting around duplicating code in complex if/else statements

Tags: php

I come across this problem all the time: you have a series of `if/else` statements, where the intended result can come from two completely different branches, and you end up duplicating the code across both. Here's an example:

```
if (condition1) {
    return error
} else {
    if (condition2) {
        return intendedResult
    } else {
        if (condition3) {
            return error
        } else {
            return intendedResult
        }
    }
}
```

I have this problem in a PHP script at the moment, where the intended result is approximately 200 lines of PHP queries, HTML and additional `if/else` statements. Is this the prime example of when you should use a function? And `return` all that code in a concatenated string?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all your replies. I can see that my logic would need tidying up. If I gave you a real-world example, could you help me restructure my logic? I think it's a little more complicated than my pseudo-code.

I pull two dates, `$lift_deadline` and `$show_guide_close` from a database, and depending on today's date's relation to those, do the following:

```
if ($lift_deadline > $today) {
    echo "No access until " . $lift_deadline;
} else {
    if ($lift_deadline !== "0000-00-00") {
        if ($today > $show_guide_close) {
            $use_date = $show_guide_close;
        } else {
            $use_date = $lift_deadline;
        }
        echo "HTML Table"; // Intended result goes here, using $use_date
    } else {
        if ($show_guide_close > $today) {
            echo "No access until " . $show_guide_close;
        } else {
            $use_date = $show_guide_close;
            echo "HTML Table"; // Intended result also goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code you provided isn't complex. It could simply be written like this `if (condition1 || condition3) { return error } else { return intendedResult }` Yes, intendedResult should be a function! So should error!

Comment: Should be `if (condition1 || (!condition2 &&  condition3)) { return error } else { return intendedResult }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well part of the solution is certainly making `intendedResult` code into a separate method, but just reoganizing the conditions can help:

```
if ($condition1) {
    return 'error';
}
if (!$condition2 && $condition3) {
    return 'error';
}
return $this->intendedResult();
```

This could be further simplified to:

```
return ($condition1 || $condition3) ? 'error' : $this->intendedResult();
```

But that might not be as readable, and doesnt really illustrate my point, which is as Tom mentions, to flatten your control structure

Comment: Beat me to it so I'll place my rational here: Since a return ends the process flow, you can flatten your logic by placing the check for when you return an error (or throw an exception) at the top of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, functions are one way to simplify code and make it easier to read. It might be also worth looking into [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.classobj.php) and [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: To me though, endless `$returnVar .= ...` inside the function before a `return $returnVar` doesn't *feel* right...

Comment: Functions are supposed to be short and snappy. You should aim for functions so that there is only one return at the end of the function. Using object/classes and functions will almost automatically change the way you structure your code and your conditions and be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In simple instances I use a switch statement for stuff like this

```
switch(true)
{
    case (condition1):

        break;
    case (condition2):

        break;
    default:

}
```